# How to save my plant?

Tags: leaves, plant-care

I don't exactly know the name of my plant, but it seriously need some help. Over the course of time it grown long and shred the lower bottom leaves that leaves a long stem. I am not sure what kind of pot I have to move it in, or what else I could do to save it. Anyone suggest a solution?

[image]

Comment: It is so fragile that it is not easy to move here and there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a *Dracaena fragrans*. Your plant is doing great, however it is getting to large (tall). This plant is a very popular house plant, because it doesn't need much water nor much (direct sun-)light.

What you can do is to prune it. You could for example cut off the top, and let the bare stem grow in the pot (new shoots will emerge). Or you can replant the top as well, it will root soon if you just cut off the top and put that in a new pot of soil. Don't keep the soil too moist during propagation (it can cause rot). Or you can put it in water and let it root in there.

You can also do both! Let both the bottom and top grow into new plants.

Also you can cut the long stem in many smaller pieces and put them all in fresh soil. Give the new small plants to friends or family as a small present. See e.g., [here](https://www.joyusgarden.com/accidentally-propagated-dracaena/) for more about propagation.

Comment: I thought of doing it but was afraid that I turn up lossing my plant. Thanks for reply :-)

Comment: If you want to play save, chop the cane in more pieces and put them in one pot, like [here](https://www.patchplants.com/gb/en/plants/dracaena-fragrans-52/). Then you know for sure that some will survive.